# Type issue of ref using EmailJS and Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, astrojs

I'm new to React and I use the Astro framework. I would like to add a contact form to my landing page and to do so I use the EmailJS service. I tried to get the example in documentation of EmailJS for React and adapt it to Typescript but I can't understand this error:

> Type '{ children: any[]; ref: MutableRefObject<string |
> HTMLFormElement>; onSubmit: (e: any) => void; }' is not assignable to
> type 'FormHTMLAttributes'.   Property 'ref' does not exist on type
> 'FormHTMLAttributes'.

My code in following:

```
import ContentSection from "~/components/content-section.astro";
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import emailjs from '@emailjs/browser';

export const ContactUs = () => {
  const form = useRef() as React.MutableRefObject<string | HTMLFormElement>;

  const sendEmail = (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    emailjs.sendForm('YOUR_SERVICE_ID', 'YOUR_TEMPLATE_ID', form.current, 'YOUR_PUBLIC_KEY')
      .then((result) => {
          console.log(result.text);
      }, (error) => {
          console.log(error.text);
      });
  };

  return (
    <form ref={form} onSubmit={sendEmail}>
      <label>Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="user_name" />
      <label>Email</label>
      <input type="email" name="user_email" />
      <label>Message</label>
      <textarea name="message" />
      <input type="submit" value="Send" />
    </form>
  );
};

---

<ContentSection title="Nous contacter" id="contact">
  <Fragment slot="lead">
    Vous avez besoin de <span class="text-primary">renseignements</span> ?
    N'hésitez pas une seconde et contactez-nous !
  </Fragment>
  <div class="max-w-6xl space-y-2">
    <ContactUs />
  </div>
</ContentSection>
```

Thanks for help,
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe having the same name for the `ref` as the HTML element is overriding its type declaration.

Try changing `form` to something like `formRef`, and see if it fixes the type issue.

```js
export const ContactUs = () => {
    const formRef = useRef<HTMLFormElement>(null);
    ..
    ..
    return (
        <form ref={formRef} onSubmit={sendEmail}>
          ..
        </form>
    );
}
```

Comment: I change null by '' because null was not accepted. But I still have the same error with the ref attribute underlined